# How can I use a model from another model in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I have this structure:

```
application
      controllers
            ...
      models
            acl
                api.php
                ...
            user.php
            ...
      ...
```

In user.php I have Application_Model_User class and in api.php I have Application_Model_Acl_Api class. In bootstrap.php I have this code:

```
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => 'Application',
    ));
    $resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(
        array(
            'model' => array
            ( 'path'      => 'models/acl',
            'namespace' => 'Model_Acl' ),
        )    
    );
```

If in user.php I use `new Application_Model_Acl_Api` it will give me an error: "Class not found." How can I solve this error???

BTW please don't tell me to put `include_once('acl/api.php');` at the beginning of the file. It's a big application, if I do that, then I will have to do it for every single model.

Comment: What happens when you add `$resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(
        array(
            'model' => array
            ( 'path'      => 'models/',
            'namespace' => 'Model_' ),
        )    
    );`

Comment: nothing happens ... Don't get me wrong but the application works. If i move api.php in models it works fine but I want my application to be structured on folders

Comment: is the user model being autoloaded or are you including that one in?

Comment: What if you try new Model_Acl_Api(); instead of Application_Model_Acl_Api ?

Comment: same thing Fatal error: Class 'Model_Acl_Api' not found 
I've tried this things.... I've tried to wrote the acl folder acl and Acl.... I've tried new Acl_Api(); new Api(); nothing worked.

Comment: I would love to see the first line from your class file Api.php and also the actual file name (thinking about Linux here). I did some various simple typos over the years and it drove me nuts each and every single time.

Comment: the name of the file is: api.php
and the first line is: class Application_Model_Acl_Api extends Zend_Acl implements AclInterface